# How to delete the certain data from array

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am new in ionic 4. I am doing shopping cart function. I want to delete the selected item. But it delete like pop function not delete the certain item. I have follow this tutorial : https://devdactic.com/dynamic-ionic-4-slides/

In service ts I am using this function
then
Cart.page.ts

```
onDeleteItem(i) {
const index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(i);
if (index > -1) {
this.cartServ.deleteFromCart(i);
this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
console.log(this.selectedItems);
}
this.total = this.selectedItems.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.count * b.price), 0);
}
```

Cart.service

```
    addToCart(product) {
        this.cartService.addProduct(product);
      }


    deleteFromCart(i) {
    const index = this.cart.indexOf(i);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.cart.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is there is reason why you are using 2 duplicate lists.  There should be a master list in the Cart service that the `Cart.page.ts` retrieves with a `getter()`.  You shouldn't be maintaining 2 identical lists.

Comment: you should debug your code and watch variable's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the `index` to `deleteFromCart` function.

**The reason is `index` of the deleting item in `selectedItems` array may not be the same index in `cart` items Array.**

Pass the `i` which is the item, to `deleteFromCart` function and find the `index` and use `splice`.

```
onDeleteItem(i) {
    ...
    this.cartServ.deleteFromCart(i);
    ...
}

deleteFromCart(i) {
   const items = this.cart.filter(item => item.id === i.id);
   const index = this.cart.indexOf(items[0])
   if (index > -1) {
        this.cart.splice(index, 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already update my coding but after I change it did not change anything.

Comment: check whether value of index in deleteFromCart is not equal to -1

Comment: not length. I need to know value of index variable . `deleteFromCart(i) {
    const index = this.cart.indexOf(i);
    console.log(index)
    if (index > -1) {
        this.cart.splice(index, 1);
    }
}`

Comment: ok that is the reason can you tell me what are attributes of the elements in selectedItems array

Comment: is item id, I totally follow this website https://devdactic.com/dynamic-ionic-4-slides/